# powershell cmdlet: expression must be readable

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

My cmdlet is trying to get values from pipeline, but when running, I got the error saying:

Pipeline intput cannot be processed because the default value of parameter 'Legalentity' cannot be retrived. Exception getting 'Legalentity' : expression must be readable
Parameter Name: expression

and I have no idea what produces this error..

Thanks for any help! The code is below..

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Deals")]
public partial class GetDealCmdlet : InsightBaseCmdlet
{
    private List<Object> _legalentities = new List<Object>();
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    public List<Object> Legalentity { set { _legalentities = value; } } 


    protected override void ProcessRecord() {...}
}
```

and the usage:

```
Search-Deals xxx | Get-Deals
```

where search-Deals is:

```
...

protected override void ProcessRecord() 
{
    foreach (PSObject in List<PSObject>)
    {
        ....
        writeObject(PSObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cmdlet says parameter cannot be retrieved: expression must be readable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888909/cmdlet-says-parameter-cannot-be-retrieved-expression-must-be-readable)

Answer (score 0):

Making sure your `Parameter` has both a `get`ter and a `set`ter should solve the problem as well as any `"Expression must be writeable"` errors of a similar type.

```
public List<Object> Legalentity 
{ 
    set { _legalentities = value; } 
    get { return _legalentities; }
}
```