# cmdlet says parameter cannot be retrieved: expression must be readable

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

My cmdlet has a `Get-Deal` command, which will receive value from pipeline:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Deal")]
public class GetDealCmdlet : InsightBaseCmdlet
{
    private List<Object> _legalentities = new List<Object>();
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
    public List<Object> Legalentity { set { _legalentities = value; } } 


    protected override void ProcessRecord() {...}
}
```

It works fine if I passed a list of string or other types. However if I passed an object that is created in `Search-Deal`:

```
foreach (...)
{
    PSObject dealValue = new PSObject();
    dealValue.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty(Legalentity,Convert.ToInt32($deal.Properties["LegalEntityID"].Value.ToString())));
    dealValue.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Name",deal.Properties["name"].Value.ToString()));
    WriteObject(dealValue);
}
```

I get an error :

> Pipeline input cannot be processed because the default value of parameter 'Legalentity' cannot be retrieved. Exception getting 'Legalentity' : expression must be readable Parameter Name: expression

I am sure that the `search-Deal` works fine because

```
$a = Search-Deal name
```

is working. And giving:

```
Get-Deal $a
```

returns the exact result that I want.

However

```
$a | Get-Deal
```

will error out by the same one too.

EDIT:
using

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Search-Deal JL | Get-Deal } -PSHost
```

I found the following:

```
CALLING BeginProcessing 
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Get-Deal] 
PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] 
RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values 
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default] 
PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] 
Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION 
BIND arg [Pipeline input cannot be processed because the default value of parameter 'LegalEntity' cannot be retrieved. Exception getting "LegalEntity": "Expression must be readable Parameter name: expression"]
```

So I think it must be something wrong with the pipeline passing objects.

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the public List Legalentity { set { _legalentities = value; } }  is missing the getter.

although I don't really know the reason behind it, adding the get {return xxx } will eliminate the error.

The error then makes sense. It is basically telling that you need to add a getter:

Pipeline input cannot be processed because the default value of parameter 'Legalentity' cannot be retrieved. Exception getting 'Legalentity' : expression must be readable Parameter Name: expression

Answer (score 2):

The way PowerShell pipeline works will prevent this kind of scenario.
Instaed of passing whole list - it will pass elements one by one. To prevent it from happening you can use unary comma:

```
, $a | Get-Deals
```

However my suggestion (as PowerShell user): do not do it, unless you have very good reason. Instead, accept/ write single objects. This is more natural and should spare future user similar griefs you have now (quite opposite actually - I would expect stream of objects returned rather than single "bloat" ;) )

Also: good practice is to name cmdlets with singular noun. Even if you expect more usually (Get-Process, Get-Service, Get-ChildItem...)

Comment: Renamed to be singular :) To be more specific, the Search-Deal writes object within a loop: foreach (){PSObject dealValue = new PSObject(); ... WriteObject(dealValue);} so it passes one object a time. also Get-Deal can take a list(which preserves the ability to pass in a list variable to the parameter instead of pipelining as shown) , but in the pipeline case, I think it takes one object a time from the previous loop. I tried , $a | Get-Deals but doesn't seem like working though...

Comment: I must been reading it wrong the first time. Anyway: I would check `Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding` - clearly, something in parameter binder is causing this issue, so more trace information may be helpful. I see property that matches parameter in the Search-Deal output object, maybe that is causing this issue? Last but not least: I see `$deal` within `ToInt32`, shouldn't it be `deal` instead...?

Comment: The $deal is another PSObject that the Search-deal takes the id and pass it to pipeline as a property of the dealValue. I kinda make it $deal to identify it is a variable :) I am not familiar with Trace-Command and I used: Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding {Search-Deal JL | Get-Deal} and the same error is given.. Could you please tell me how should I use the Trace-Command? Also, You mentioned property that matches parameter in the Search-Deal output object, and this could cause the problem. I tried renaming the parameter's name of Get-Deal but doesn't help much here..

Comment: Do you think that when I am passing a PSObject to Get-Deal, the comdlet doesn't recognize the PSObject as it is expecting List<PSObject> ?

Comment: OK, you are developer here, I just see `$deal` used in one property and `deal` in the other. Regarding trace: you need to direct output somewhere, `-PSHost` for starters, e.g. `Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Search-Deal | Get-Deal } -PSHost`. Reason? If input object type matches type of parameter - it will be used. Than if there is property named same as parameter, it will be bound second. Lastly input object will be convert to type that parameter expects. With trace you should be able to tell when it fails so badly.

Comment: CALLING BeginProcessing
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Get-Deal]
PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default]
PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
Parameter [InputObject] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
BIND arg [Pipeline input cannot be processed because the default value of parameter 'LegalEntity' cannot be
retrieved. Exception getting "LegalEntity": "Expression must be readable
Parameter name: expression"]

Comment: the Trace-Command tells me that it finds something error: PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] but I have no idea what it is and how this can be fixed...